# Programmatically switching to the "More" tab on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I want to programmatically initialise my tabBarController to the last tab selected by the user.  This works OK for my standard tabs, but if the uwer was on the "more" tab, I cannot figure out how to initialise it as this tab doesn't (to my knowledge) have an index).

Is anyone aware of a way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the `-[UITabBarController selectedIndex]` documentation:

> To select the More navigation
>   controller itself, you must change the
>   value of the selectedViewController
>   property instead

So just do:

```
[controller setSelectedViewController:[controller moreNavigationController]];
```

Comment: Thank you!  Not sure why I didn't find that:)

Comment: Is it possible to switch to the edit mode of the more screen directly?    Something like `[controller moreNavigationController].editing = YES;`